# Append Whitespace to stringbuilder?

Tags: c#, stringbuilder

How do I append white space to a string builder? I need to insert 90 blank spaces, in `VB` i had this code but i was confused how to write in `c#` can any one help me

```
Dim S As New StringBuilder("HELLO")
S.Append(" "c, 90)
S.Append("WORLD")
MessageBox.Show(S.ToString)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps searching for "StringBuilder C#" with your favorite search engine would help...? Top search result for me is http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2839d5h5(v=vs.71).aspx - voila, C# example code for StringBuilder.

Comment: In the future, I recommend using this site to translate between C# and VB.NET: http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
S.Append(' ', 90);
```

that ought to do it.

Answer (score 9):

```
StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder().Append("Hello").Append(' ', 90).Append("world");
```